# Why not just have a stack or just a heap alone?

Tags: java, memory, stack, heap-memory

Not sure if heap or stack is just in a Java, but why have two separate things to hold memory? Why not just have an unlimited stack, or just have a an unlimited heap? What’s the purpose of having them separate, or the reasoning to design it like that? I think I understand the difference between the two at a beginner level.

Comment: [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

Comment: Without a heap: What is your suggestion to share objects between any two different stackframes?

Comment: @akuzminykh Or between two threads? Each thread has its own stack, whereas the heap is shared between all threads. Maybe this was what you meant.

Comment: @OleV.V. Both examples show that a heap is damn useful. :) I meant: If function `A` calls `B` and `x` is created in `B`, how do you use `x` in `C` where `C` is a call that happens after the call to `B`?

Comment: @OleV.V. Of course with `x` being an object and not a primitive data type or a reference.

Comment: @akuzminykh Your point is good, and thanks for explaining. In my head I began designing a JVM that should be able to that. Allow me to say that my design got hopeless very, very quickly!